# what' the pythonic way to do this?

Tags: python

I want to write some shorthand expression in while(like c),but it wouldn't work in python.

```
while token=TokenBuffer.peek() and token != sentinel
    doSomeThing()
```

Answer (score 7):

You can't do this in Python. Assignments are statements in Python, not expressions.

So, what can you do instead? The most pythonic is probably using the [`iter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#iter) function:

```
for token in iter(TokenBuffer.peek, sentinel):
```

The docs for this are a little confusing to a novice:

> … If the second argument, *sentinel*, is given, then object must be a callable object. The iterator created in this case will call object with no arguments for each call to its `__next__()` method; if the value returned is equal to *sentinel*, `StopIteration` will be raised, otherwise the value will be returned.

That's great if you already understand how iterators and for loops work under the covers, but if you don't, the example below may be more helpful:

> One useful application of the second form of `iter()` is to read lines of a file until a certain line is reached. The following example reads a file until the `readline()` method returns an empty string:

```
with open('mydata.txt') as fp:
    for line in iter(fp.readline, ''):
        process_line(line)
```

That makes it a lot clearer: `for line in iter(fp.readline, ''):` calls `fp.readline()` over and over until it gets a `''`. Just like you want to do calling `TokenBuffer.peek()` over and over until it gets a `sentinel`.

Comment: Note that most of the time this is a symptom of poor design - much better is just building an `__iter__` or a method that returns an iterable (eg. for the file example, one would do `for line in fp: ...`).

Comment: @Veedrac: But `for line in fp:` doesn't stop at the first empty line, so it's not a general-purpose replacement. (Yes, it's a bad example, because `readline` only returns an empty line at EOF, not at a blank line… but it's a bad example from the official docs, so…) Sure, you could use `for line in takewhile(bool, fp):` or something, but I don't think that's clearer.

Comment: `readline` includes line-ends, so it won't stop until the end of the file (blank lines will still give `'\n'`). Anyway, I agree with what you've written in the answer - my comment was for the OP.

Comment: @Veedrac: My comment already says that, inside the parentheses. (And the sad thing is, they could easily have made it a good example without making it incomprehensible. For example, if you had `map(str.rstrip, fp)` instead of `fp`, then the `iter` function would read the RFC822 header and leave the body for later, while the `for` loop would read the whole file. Although a completely different example, like `iter(sock.recv, b'')` would probably be better.)

Comment: Whoops, not sure how I missed your parenthetical.

Comment: @Veedrac: I probably could have made it clearer by acknowledging that it was a bad example first, then covering the presumable intent, rather than vice-versa… And maybe I shouldn't have quoted the docs' example in the first place, just to avoid this confusion? I can always edit the answer; what do you think?

Comment: Personally I think the answer is fine - it answers the question and the example is simple. Reimplementing `__iter__` is fine as long as it's not in production ;).